# Set type of params in react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

How to pass params in URL matching type?

For example I have `/profile/:id` which allows me to go `/profile/1`.

But problem is I can also go by `/profile/1qwr/` and I'll get nothing.

How to check the type of the URL parameter and show error or something else?

Comment: how do you fetch profiles ? by making some sort of request with the id to the database?

Answer (score 13):

**For version 6 and above**:

This answer is outdated since v6. [See discussion on Github](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/discussions/8132) (thanks to @dan for pointing this out).

---

**For version 5 and below**:

Best solution, in my opinion, is to set a *type* on the `id` parameter by writing a simple regular expression.

If you want the id to accept only integers, this is what you'll do:

```
/profile/:id(\\d+)

/* the `(\\d+)` is a regular expression that will only accept integers */
```

---

Read more about this in [`path-to-regex`](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp#custom-matching-parameters) documentation. `path-to-regex` is used by react-router internally, so there's no need to install anything.

Comment: This is correct. As an addendum, if your parameter is optional you can use it like this:

`/profile/:id(\\d+)?`

`'/profile/1' = { id: 1 }`

`'/profile/two' = {}`

`'/profile' = {}`

Comment: It seems like this is not supported with v6: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/discussions/8132

Answer (score 5):

A. You cannot set type checking on params of the route.

B. If you want to show some error - handle it in your render method by getting the param like this `this.props.params.id`. But even here you cannot differentiate between the type because you will always get the string.

You can try using `parseInt` and check if the conversion is successful or not and determine then what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Quick hack I just thought of:

In `componentWillMount()` (or in the render function of a Pure Component, but that's probably a worse idea), you can reference the URL being passed with `this.props.match.url`.

You can slice the string to eliminate the `/` and then pass the url to regex or a function like `parseInt()` for quasi-type-checking.

All you'd need to do then is pull in the [Redirect component](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect) from `react-router` and conditionally fire it off (probably to send it your 404 page if it's not the type you're allowing.).

Comment: componentWillMount will be deprecate. https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html